# Encrypted my private folder on a local network and couldn't open it

Tags: windows-7, networking, encryption, administrator, decryption

I have an account on my company local network and tried to encrypt my private folder and saved the key.
but i can't open it even though i have the key and it says " access is denied " and i don't have the admin rights.

is there any way to open it again?

Comment: If you do not have the key that was used to encrypt the files then the files cannot be accessed.  You should talk to your IT Administrator so they can take appropriate actions to assist you.  This cannot be solved without Administrator permissions, even with Administrator rights if they files are encrypted, without a key nothing can be done except restore from backup.

Comment: i have the key i encrypted myself and don't know just how to open it.